# Парсинг JSON с одинаковыми значениями Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular2

Имеется следующая структура данных:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "treaty_number": "number1",
        "model": "type1",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "treaty_number": "number2",
        "model": "type2",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "treaty_number": "number3",
        "model": "type1",
    },
]
```

Как данный JSON записать в новый словарь и оставить только те данные, у которых значение "model": "type1", а остальные удалить?

Comment: Вероятно, поможет метод [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): `let jsonNew = json.filter(element => element.model === 'type1');`

Comment: @diaria, спасибо!
А если я изначально не знаю, какие "model" с одинаковым типом?

Comment: Не очень понял вопрос. Массив всех типов можно получить вот так: `[...new Set(json.map(element => element.model))]`. Опишите, пожалуйста, подробней что вы хотите.

Comment: @diaria, мы здесь явно указали, найти с type1 `element.model === 'type1'`, а как пройти по json'у и задать условие, чтобы вытащить все "model" с одинаковым значением?

Comment: А если в json будут две модели с `.model === 'type1'` и две с `.model === 'type2'`, то надо получить первые две или вторые две?

Comment: @diaria, обе:) Я к тому, что если я не знаю, какой тип там записан, но нужно вытащить одинаковые

Comment: Что-нибудь [такое](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38327540/5812238)? Копируете функцию `groupBy`, вызываете её так: `groupBy(json, element => element.model)`, получаете объект (если что объект и массив это не одно и то же), в котором ключи это типы (`type1`, `type2`), а значения это массивы объектов, имеющих соответствующий тип

Comment: @diaria, единственное он возвращает объекты со значениями, в массивах которых - могут находится модели с одним типом, а не одинаковые

Comment: Ну да. Вам, видимо, надо что-то другое, но я пока не могу понять что. Может вот так подойдёт: [`_.uniqWith(array, _.isEqual)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40676069/5812238) (используется библиотека lodash)